# complex reductive Lie group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I am reading A. L. Oniscik's paper *Decompositions of Reductive Lie Groups*, and the author cited a proposition that a complex reductive  Lie group $G=ZS$ is locally isomorphic to the reductive algebraic group $\widetilde G= \mathbb C^{m}\times S$. I want to have a reference about this proposition. Any reference will be helpful. Thanks.